# How to grep specific letters in a sequence using grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I have a file containing this form of information:

```
>scaffold1|size69534
ACATAAGAGSTGATGATAGATAGATGCAGATGACAGATGANNGTGANNNNNNNNNNNNNTAGAT
>scaffold2|size68281
ATAGAGATGAGACAGATGACAGANNNNAGATAGATAGAGCAGATAGACANNNNAGATAGAG
>scaffold3|size67203
ATAGAGTAGAGAGAGAGTACAGATAGAGGAGAGAGATAGACNNNNNNACATYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
>scaffold4|size66423
ACAGATAGCAGATAGACAGATNNNNNNNAGATAGTAGACSSSSSSSSSS
```

and so on

But I guess there is something abnormal in the sequence , so what I want to is to grep all the lettres that are not A, C, T, G or N in all the lines after scaffold 
(I want to search just in the lines where the sequence is not in the line >scaffold-size ).
In the example above it will grep YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY after scaffold3  and SSSSSSSSSSSSS in scaffold 4.
I hope I'm clear enough , please if you need any clarification tell me.

Thank you

Comment: can you explain why it will grep 'YYYY...' after scaffold3? what are the rules that you have in mind to identify this segment? are you open to other commands such as perl or sed?

Comment: Hello , thank you for your reply , i mean thats what i want to do , in all the lines except the line >scaffold-size , i want to grep all the lettres that are not A - C - G - T - N that s what i want to do  , in the exemple above i want command that will  grep YYYYYYYY and SSSSSSS , and yes , i can sed will be good to use too

Comment: `egrep '[^ACTGN]'`?

Comment: @MejaitAnouar, could you please check my answer once and lemme know if that helped you?

Comment: (1) As the answers already posted show, you missed one of the invalid sequences already. (2) Do you just want to see the offending bits, or the whole sequence that has bad bits in it? (3) Don't you also want to know which **scaffold** each bad sequence belongs to? That would make the question more interesting. (4) Can we assume that the sequences are all uppercase letters (so we don't need to look for other characters) and there are no uppercase letters on the `>` rows? (5) Are you seriously storing this kind of data in a flat text file, not in a database (or even in Excel)? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you don't just need to know which sequences contain invalid characters - you also want to know which scaffold each sequence belongs to. This can be done; how to do it depends on the exact output format you need, and also on the exact structure of the data.

Just for illustration, I will make the following simplifying assumptions: the "sequences" may only contain uppercase letters (which may be the valid ones **or** invalid ones - but there can't be punctuation marks, or digits, etc.); and the labels (the rows that begin with a `>`) don't contain any uppercase letters. Note - if the sequences only contain letters, then it's not too hard to pre-process the file to convert the sequences to all-uppercase and the labels to all-lowercase, so the solution below will still work.

In some versions of GREP, the invalid characters will appear in a different color (see the linked image). I find this quite helpful.

```
grep --no-group-separator -B 1 '[BDEFHIJKLMOPQRSUVWXYZ]' input_file
```

OUTPUT:

```
>scaffold1|size69534
ACATAAGAGSTGATGATAGATAGATGCAGATGACAGATGANNGTGANNNNNNNNNNNNNTAGAT
>scaffold3|size67203
ATAGAGTAGAGAGAGAGTACAGATAGAGGAGAGAGATAGACNNNNNNACATYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
>scaffold4|size66423
ACAGATAGCAGATAGACAGATNNNNNNNAGATAGTAGACSSSSSSSSSS
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, considering that you don't want empty lines then try following.

```
awk '!/^>/{gsub(/[ACTGN]/,"");if(NF){print}}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program from here.
!/^>/{                   ##Checking condition if a line does not starts from > then do following.
  gsub(/[ACTGN]/,"")     ##Globally substituting A,C,T,G,N will NULL in lines here.
  if(NF){                ##Checking condition if current is NOT NULL after substitution then do following.
    print                ##Print the current line.
  }
}
'  Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
S
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
SSSSSSSSSS
```

Answer (score 0):

use `grep -v` to remove the scaffold lines, and use grep -oP to select the segments of undesired letters.

```
cat test.txt | grep -v '^>' | grep -oP '[^ACGTN]+'
```

output from the sample data

```
S
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
SSSSSSSSSS
```